# How to set loop with multiple changing values python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a set of equations that I want to run multiple values of a variable `H` through and I want these equations evaluated over a range of values I have. My code **roughly** looks as follows;

```
  k=m=1
  x_values = []
  v_values = []
  N = np.array([10,100,1000]) 
  H = (tb-ta)/N 
  for n in np.arange(ta,tb+H,H):
        if n ==0:
          vn = v0 + x0*H*-(k/m)
          xn = x0 + v0*H

          x_values.append(xn)
          v_values.append(vn)

        if n>0:
          v_next = vn + xn*h*-(k/m)
          x_next = xn + vn*h
          vn = v_next
          xn = x_next

          x_values.append(x_next)
          v_values.append(v_next)
```

What I want to happen is the values of the `arange` to be calculated for each `H` values and for the equations to loop through and store the values for each of these loops for the different `H` values.

Do I need to store these in lists instead of arrays? Also do I need more empty arrays or arrays to store the separate values in? Eventually I want to plot each set of values calculated from the `H` values.

Comment: So, are you getting an error, or what?

Comment: You know `H`, `vn` and `xn` are only calculated once in your code right?

Comment: yes, I know...this isn't the whole code. I need to do some serious updates to the question including giving the error code I have been given. I will be updating the question now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to nest loops, one inside the other.  The outer loop runs through the values of H; the inner loop does the calculations from there.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
k=m=1
x_values = []
v_values = []
N = np.array([10,100,1000]) 
for slice_count in [10,100,1000]:
    H = (tb-ta)/slice_count
    for n in np.arange(ta,tb+H,H):
        if n ==0:
          vn = v0 + x0*H*-(k/m)
          xn = x0 + v0*H

          x_values.append(xn)
          v_values.append(vn)

        if n>0:
          v_next = vn + xn*h*-(k/m)
          x_next = xn + vn*h
          vn = v_next
          xn = x_next

          x_values.append(x_next)
          v_values.append(v_next)
```